# Angular 4: Calling Regex patterns from an Object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm having an issue where the code is working but I'm getting a Tslint error that I can't figure out. This setup worked when using Angular 1 but now I'm converting the application to 4 using angular-cli.

> Angular: Identifier 'vin' is not defined. Object does not contain such
>   a member.

I have shared Regex patterns stored in an Object shown below. It gets imported into my component and is then called using `[pattern]="patterns.KEY"`.

The pattern works just like it should and validation is working but I'm still getting the above error when I attach it to any of my inputs. Is it because I'm missing data types on `patterns`? If so, how would it be defined?

The error is only thrown on the template file. The component and Patterns file do not have any validation errors.

**Template Code:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="vin">VIN</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vin" placeholder="VIN"
           minlength="8" maxlength="17" required [pattern]="patterns.vin"
           [(ngModel)]="model.Vin" name="Vin" #Vin="ngModel">
  </div>
```

**Component code:**

```
export class COMPONENT_NAME implements OnInit {
  patterns = Patterns;
}
```

**Patterns file:**

```
export const Patterns: Object = {
  vin: /^[\w\d]+$/i,
};
```

Comment: It's working for me in [this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Qx9SFvsMVkOthmH53vGZ?p=preview) have you imported from the file correctly? Edit: plunk updated with input: must start with `a` and all other criteria met

Comment: @0mpurdy it's throwing a lint error on the template file but it renders fine. More of an annoying problem, not a breaking problem.

Comment: as sorry I didn't understand it was a lint issue try not typing it as `Object` and let typescript infer what types it has (or create an interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer was pretty simple. `patterns` needed to be defined but the value needed to be set inside `ngOnInit()`:

```
export class COMPONENT_NAME implements OnInit {
  patterns;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.patterns = Patterns;
  }
}
```

This removes the Tslint issue I was seeing.